# Question about matrix equation and it's simplification

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

For example, we had such an equation (where A is a matrix, and we need to find X, also where T is transpose) -

A = $(2 \cdot X)^T$

So, we will have something like this? According to the sources which I found.

$$A = X^T \cdot 2 \cdot I^T$$

$$X^T = A \cdot (2 \cdot I^T)^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Scalars, such as 2 are not effected by transposition, since transposing only makes rows columns and the other way around, so multiplying *all entries* of the matrix with two before or after transposing doesn't make a difference:
$$
A = (2 X)^T = 2 X^T.
$$
More precisely one could write
$$
(2 X)^T = (2 I \cdot X)^T
= X^T \cdot (2 I)^T
= X^T \cdot 2 (I)^T
= X^T \cdot 2 (I)
= 2 X^T,
$$
but we still need the above demonstrated fact $(\lambda A)^T = \lambda A^T$.

Solving for $X$, we have
$$
A = 2 X^T
\implies X^T = \frac{1}{2} A
\implies \left(X^T\right)^T = \left(  \frac{1}{2} A \right)^T
\implies X = \frac{1}{2} A^T.
$$

Also, your way is correct, since your last result simplifies as follows.
$$
X^T = A \cdot (2 \cdot I^T)^{-1}
= A \cdot 2^{-1} I^{-T}
= \frac{1}{2} A,
$$
which is my second step from above.